# Recuperar id insertado angular y php

Tags: angular

Estoy insertando unos datos en mi base de datos, pero necesito saber el id con el que se está insertando osea recuperar ese id.

No tengo ni idea de como recuperarlo, lo único que se me a ocurrido hasta ahora es

```
addHojaingresomedica() {
this.hojaIngresoMedica = new HojaIngresoMedica(null, datos, datos, datos);
this._pai.addHojaingresomedica(this.hojaIngresoMedica).subscribe(
        result => {
            if(result['code'] == 200) {
                this.getFormularios();
                this._router.navigate(['/prueba']);
            } else {
            }
         },
         error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
         }
        );
```

Comment: Estás usando una base sql o no sql?

Comment: Si estas llamado a una API sera la API quien te tenga que indicar el id, por lo que tendrías que mostrar el código PHP de como insertas el dato. Desde Angular poco puedes hacer.